# Data normalization to use as input in ML algorithms

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation, normalize

I would like to get some suggestions about the best way to normalize my dataset to use as ML inputs.

My dataset looks like this:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   date   | holiday | weekday |  type  | max_temp | min_temp |   qty   |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 01/31/22 |    0    |   tue   | casual |   35.25  |  23.44   |  1,358  |
 2  | 07/02/21 |    1    |   mon   | member |   34.33  |   7.29   |  1,358  |    
 3  | 03/12/20 |    0    |   sat   | casual |   12.21  |   2.18   |  1,358  |    
... 
 n
```

I'm using Python to clean the data, and I intend to use this dataset to apply some linear regression, random forests, and XGBoost algorithm to predict the last column (qty).

Any suggestions for the best practice to prepare my data?

Comment: From my previous experience, I know that it's possible to turn all data into dummies, but that is the really the best practice? I think about to create more columns and fill with 0 and 1 for the different classifications of the categorical data, but i am not certainly about increasing the size of the dataset.

Comment: The question is too broad. I recommend you the book hands on Machine Learning from Aurelien Geron. Regards.

Comment: Searching, I found that a good way is to convert categorical data into dummy variables with the "pd.get_dummies()". I will try to do this.

Comment: There are specific functions for that in scikit learn. Have a look to ordinal encoder, one hot encoder, label encoder. Each one has a specific use. Regards.

Comment: Thank you @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos, for my dataset, I think that the most adequate is to turn the categorial data into dummies through "one hot encoder". I tried that on my notebook and looks good. I am going now to see if the ML model runs OK with that methodology.

Comment: Great buddy!!!, be aware that some models need to scale your numerical values. Other ones don't need that.